# React native: How to use Flatlist with other views in a component

Tags: react-native

I am using `"react-native": "^0.50.4"`, and this is how component`render` looks like:

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View>
                ....
            </View>

            <FlatlistComponent /> 
        </View>
    );
}
```

[image]

The above `FlatlistComponent` renders a list, except the last item is partially shown/pushed down, this is because the `View` above the flatlist, how do I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

If the FlatList disappears when you add a style of flex: 1, you must continue moving up the hierarchy of elements, adding flex, until the FlatList finally appears.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the View component other then the flat list is taking up the whole space of the flex 1. Flatlist being scrollable it is supposed to go down.

Try assigning separate flex values to the child components.

```
render(){
    return(
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{flex: 1}>
                <View>
                  ....
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={{flex: 3}>
                <FlatlistComponent /> 
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, no view appears when wrapping the `Flatlist` with flex